# Total NEWB - php function if variable is null

Tags: php

sorry for asking  this dumb question i will try to explain as good as i can, i have never done a php function before, i could solve this with IF but i want to do my first function

What i want to do is to see if the variable is null and if it is i want to set the variable to be "N/A"

```
$carplate=mysql_result($result,0,"plate");
$carbrand=mysql_result($result,0,"brand");


function set_null(variablegoeshere?){
 if($WHATiWANTtonull==null){
$WHATiWANTtonull="N/A";
}else{ do nothing }
}


set_null($carplate);
set_null($carbrand);


echo "carplate = $carplate | carbrand = $carbrand";
```

i dont understand how i will get the function to set a variable to "N/A" or do nothing, i don't want it to echo something, just set a variable and i can echo it later whenever i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[EDIT]**: Use this function:

```
function set_null(&$var)
{
    if($var==null)
    {
        $var="N/A";
    }
}
```

Comment: *Attaches required "Don't use globals" warning.
Also, that doesn't do what you want. It will only work if the variable is called "$var" outside of the function. The param is pointless.

Comment: Yep, that will work.
@lawrence To explain, adding the "&" to the parameter causes it to be passed by reference. If this is your first function this is probably a little advanced. You're probably safer using functions that simply return values and assigning the returned value.